# Using the Like "*" operator in a If Statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a filter based on four combo boxes that filter records in a subform. The problem is, one value from the RowSource lists on the combo boxes do not exist in the base query.
That value is "`All`". I was planning to use the same code on all the combo boxes `AfterUpdate` event. Please see my approach below and advice where necessary. I currently get a type mismatch error on the `Me.Combobox1.Value = "Like "*""`

```
If IsNull(Me.combo1.Value) Or IsNull(Me.combo2.Value) Or IsNull(Me.combo3.Value) Or 
IsNull(Me.combo4.Value) Then
Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.combo1.Value) Or Not IsNull(combo2.Value) Or Not IsNull(combo3.Value) Or Not 
IsNull(combo4.Value) Then

If Me.combo1 = "All" Then
Me.combo1.Value = "Like " * ""
ElseIf Me.combo2.Value = "All" Then
Me.combo2.Value = "Like " * ""
ElseIf Me.combo3.Value = "All" Then
Me.combo3.Value = "Like " * ""
ElseIf Me.combo4.Value = "All" Then
Me.combo4.Value = "Like " * ""

Task1 = "SELECT * FROM qryBase WHERE [Quarter] = '" & Me.combo1.Value & "' AND [CurrentArea] = '" & 
Me.combo2.Value & "' AND [CurrentStatus] = '" & Me.combo3.Value & "' AND [MainUser] = '" & 
Me.combo4.Value & "'"

End If

End If
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work if it's fixed, but the major problem here is that when have double quotes inside of double quotes (so the inner double quotes is a literal double quote) you have to "Escape" it so that vba knows to treat it is as part of the string. The escape character is... a double quote. So it looks like `Me.combo1.Value = "Like "" * """` You also don't want spaces around your asterisk in that string, so: `Me.combo1.Value = "Like ""*"""`

Comment: @JNevill The Value passes to the combo as a string but SQL statement doesn't doesn't work on the SQL Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, your query cannot work as `LIKE` is meant to replace `=` in conditional statements. However, `LIKE` without wildcards behaves like `=`. Therefore, place the `LIKE` operator inside the SQL statement.

```vb
Dim cbo1, cbo2, cbo3, cbo4 As String
...
If Me.combo1 = "All" Then
    cbo1 = "*"
ElseIf Me.combo2.Value = "All" Then
    cbo2 = "*"
ElseIf Me.combo3.Value = "All" Then
    cbo3 = "*"
ElseIf Me.combo4.Value = "All" Then
    cbo4 = "*"
End If

Task1 = "SELECT * FROM qryBase WHERE [Quarter] LIKE '" & cbo1 & "'" _
         & " AND [CurrentArea] LIKE '" & cbo2 & "'" _
         & " AND [CurrentStatus] LIKE '" & cbo3 & "'" _
         & " AND [MainUser] LIKE '" & cbo4 & "'"

Me.frmDatasheet.Form.Recordsource = Task1
Me.frmDatasheet.Form.Requery
```

However, because combo boxes can have apostrophes, consider parameterization to avoid need of concatenating VBA values directly into SQL but bind them as parameters:

```vb
Dim qdef As QueryDef
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim sql AS String
Dim cbo1, cbo2, cbo3, cbo4 As String

sql = "PARAMETERS cbo1 TEXT, cbo2 TEXT, cbo3 TEXT, cbo4 TEXT;" _
        & "SELECT * FROM qryBase WHERE [Quarter] LIKE [cbo1]" _
        & " AND [CurrentArea] LIKE [cbo2]" _
        & " AND [CurrentStatus] LIKE [cbo3]" _
        & " AND [MainUser] LIKE [cbo4]"

If Me.combo1 = "All" Then
    cbo1 = "*"
ElseIf Me.combo2.Value = "All" Then
    cbo2 = "*"
ElseIf Me.combo3.Value = "All" Then
    cbo3 = "*"
ElseIf Me.combo4.Value = "All" Then
    cbo4 = "*"
End If

' INITIALIZE QUERY OBJECT
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", sql)
' Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedParamQuery")

' BIND PARAMS
qdef!cbo1 = cbo1
qdef!cbo2 = cbo2
qdef!cbo3 = cbo3
qdef!cbo4 = cbo4

' SET FORM RECORDSET TO EXECUTED QUERY 
Set rst = qdef.OpenRecordset()    
Set Me.frmDatasheet.Form.Recordset = rst

Set rst = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing
```

Comment: I have tried the both methods. The first Method populates the combos with `*` and does not requery the subform even after adding `Me.frmDatasheet.Form.RecordSource = Task1` and `Me.frmDatasheet.Form.Requery` The second method doesn't seems to be doing anything at all subform either. Even with `Me.frmDatasheet.Form.RedordSource = rst`

Comment: For #1, you never showed how you use *Task1*. So absolutely nothing happens after `Requery`? Try to `Debug.Print Task1` (CTRL + G in VBA editor) and manually place SQL output as record source of form in form design or even run SQL as is in query design to see if records show up. Also, I now see *Task1* in your code is placed withing the `If...ElseIf...Then..` block. Move it outside like my edited code shows.

Comment: For #2, carefully see I did not use `RecordSource` (which expects a string SQL) but `Recordset` (which expects a recordset). You should have received an error with proper error handling. Never use `On Error Goto 0` or `On Error Resume Next` which suppresses errors.

Comment: I tried and tested both methods. All work perfectly. I found that your method is a bit faster therefore, I have adopted it instead. However, I have move the SQL string beneath the if statements and added more if statements at the bottom in-order to re-fill the combos with the `All` value to avoid seeing the `*` in the combos. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Great to hear! Use VBA variables to avoid changing control values and repetitive code. See edit. Yes, parameterization is safer and more efficient that string built queries. Even better, save the SQL string as a saved query (without `"` or `&` or `_`) and avoid any SQL in VBA (use commented out line). Happy coding!